# Register function in hibernate 4.x

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am trying to register a user defined scalar function.So firstly I created a scalar function as follows:-

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER function [dbo].[fn_concatTerritory](@salesRepID int)
returns varchar(200)
As
Begin
declare @output varchar(200)    
set @output =  stuff((select ','+tm.abbreviation
from SalesRepTerritoryMap srtm
inner join TerritoryMaster tm
on
srtm.territoryID = tm.territoryID
where srtm.salesRepID = @salesRepID FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
return @output
End
```

then I have created a custom dialect (Included it in hibernate.dialect property )which is as follows:

```
public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect{

    public CustomSQLServerDialect() {
        super();

        registerFunction("fn_concatTerritory", 
            new StandardSQLFunction("[dbo].fn_concatTerritory]",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }
}
```

and used it in the following hql query:-

```
String totalRecordhql = "select SRM.salesRepID as id, SRM.firstName ,fn_concatTerritory(SRM.salesRepID)"+
"from com.rit.model.entity.salesreps.SalesRepsMaster SRM "+
"inner join SRM.salesRepTerritoryMap SRTM "+
"inner join SRTM.salesRepTerritory.territory TERR "+
"left  join TERR.prospects PM "+
"left join SRM.histories HIST "+
" group by SRM.salesRepID ,SRM.firstName";

Query query1 = getCurrentSession().createQuery(totalRecordhql);
```

But on running the program I get the following error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
+-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'fn_concatTerritory' {originalText=fn_concatTerritory}
\-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
\-[DOT] DotNode: 'salesrepsm0_.salesRepID' {propertyName=salesRepID,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=salesRepID,path=SRM.salesRepID,tableAlias=salesrepsm0_,className=com.rit.castrolcubed.model.entity.salesreps.SalesRepsMaster,classAlias=SRM}
+-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'salesrepsm0_.salesRepID' {alias=SRM, className=com.rit.castrolcubed.model.entity.salesreps.SalesRepsMaster, tableAlias=salesrepsm0_}
\-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'salesRepID' {originalText=salesRepID}

at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:154)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:859)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:649)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:663)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)...
```

**If anyone can help me out it would be great help to me as I am sitting for days.:(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved the problem.I guess it is a bug in hibernate 4.1.7 as in the below line the function name can not be a mix of capital and small letters so i changed the function name with lower case characters, and it solved the problem.
Originally:-

```
registerFunction("fn_concatTerritory", new StandardSQLFunction("dbo.fn_concatTerritory",StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
```

Changed to:

```
registerFunction("fn_concatterritory", new StandardSQLFunction("dbo.fn_concatterritory",StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
```